# Game of chicken payoff matrix for dominant strategy and nash equilibrium

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory

Consider the payoff matrix for a game of chicken:

```
                                 player II
                           YIELD         NOT YIELD
            YIELD          (3,3)          (2,4)
player I
            NOT YIELD      (4,2)          (1,1)

1. Are there dominant strategies for either party?
2. Is the outcome (YIELD,YIELD) a Nash equilibrium?
3. Is the outcome (NOT YIELD, NOT YIELD) a Nash equilibrium?
4. Is the outcome with payoff (2,4) a Nash equilibrium?
```

This was given to me as an example for our exam questions, but the teacher never gave us answers. I was just hoping someone could help me understand in the simplest possible way how I can come up with a solution (tricks appreciated too).

Answer (score 2):

1. There are no dominant strategies.
2. The outcome (yield, yield) is not a Nash-Equilibrium. Let's look at player I. Suppose Player I and II chose yield, if player I changed his to not-yield, he would get a payoff of 4 instead of just 3. Hence, there is "regret", similar argument for player II.

Can you do the rest? A general strategy for Nash Equilibrium is to think if a player could do better if he did change his strategy.

Comment: Indeed, for this game, using best responses is very quick.